# Array of a class (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, class

I cannot seem to find the correct way to write an array of a class. In this form no errors are thrown on compiling, but I receive an error when I try to make use of the array / class. The array of classes is in a class named HashTable (I'm required to write my own for an assignment) and I am testing it with the code below:

```
theHashTable.insert("aa", "ab");
```

Here is the HashTable class:

**Edit**: As pointed out by Aniket, fileNames was not being initialized. I corrected this below but receive the same error.

```
private class HashTable {       
    private class Value {
        ArrayList<String> fileNames;
        String word;
        Value() {
            fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private int currentSize = 101;
    private Value[] items;
    private HashTable() {
        items = new Value[currentSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) items[i] = new Value();
    }

    private int hash(String in) {
        int out = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) out += 37*out+in.charAt(i);
        out %= currentSize;
        if (out < 0) out += currentSize;
        return out;
    }

    public void insert(String inW, String inF) {
        int index = hash(inW);
        index = 0;
        if (items[index].word.length() == 0) {
            items[index].word = inW;
            items[index].fileNames.add(inF);
        }
        else if (items[index].word.compareTo(inW) == 0) items[index].fileNames.add(inF);
        else System.out.println("Collision");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace, or the exact error you see for better answers.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at DirHashSearch$HashTable.insert(DirHashSearch.java:165)
at DirHashSearch.tokenSearch(DirHashSearch.java:54)
at DirHashSearch.main(DirHashSearch.java:20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileNames` ArrayList in your `Values` class is never initialized. Write a constructor for `Values` and Initialize `fileNames`.

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that. Unfortunately I still have the error

Comment: @asimes - Your _Value_ constructor does not initialize the variable named _word_.  This will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown when you try to invoke _word.length()_.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `fileNames` in your inner class value with initialization(line 3 in your sample code) as:

```
     ArrayList<String> fileNames = new  ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Same result. I'm pretty sure the meaning of my line 3 and 6 is the same as that

Comment: @asimes - You need to initialize _word_ in your _Value_ constructor.  Otherwise it will be null and it will throw a NullPointerException when you try to call _word.length()_.

Comment: This will be a theme throughout your career as a Java programmer: if you don't initialize a variable, it will be null.  You cannot invoke a method on a null object.